# renaming after 2nd underscore using rename command

Tags: bash, renaming

I had a Directory named "ABI-Data" contains files like

```
10_2012-08-22_B02_014.fsa
1_2012-08-22_A01_015.fsa
11_2012-08-22_C02_012.fsa
12_2012-08-22_D02_010.fsa
14_2012-08-22_F02_006.fsa
```

I need output like

```
abi_B02_014.fsa
abi_A01_015.fsa
abi_C02_012.fsa
abi_D02_010.fsa
abi_F02_006.fsa
```

In short I want to rename all the file up to 2nd under score with characters "abi" or anything.

I tried using rename command in working directory `ABI-Data` as

```
rename -v -n /*_*_/abi/ *.fsa
```

But found error like

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE _*_/ at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong or suggest me command/script/code that will chop all characters up to 2nd underscore and put `abi` as suffix in every file name.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this: **ReNamer** - http://www.den4b.com/?x=screenshots&product=renamer

[image: ReNamer list of functions]

Usually it does the job, you have complex Regex solutions there.

Comment: Thanks, Its another user friendly way to renaming. This is an excellent program for batch renaming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a for loop with `cut` for getting the part you want :

```
for i in `ls ABI-Data/`; do j=`echo $i|cut -d "_" -f 3-` ; mv ABI-Data/$i ABI-Data/abi_$j ; done
```

Or with `rename` :

```
rename -v  s/[^_]*_[^_]*_/abi_/ *.fsa
```

Comment: I think I am mistaking ' with `

Comment: now rename command is pretty good with my expected results. Thanks for your kind suggestions